# boost::property_tree without exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, boost, boost-propertytree

I need to parse some INI files. To do this, I'm trying to use `boost::property_tree`, but in my system exceptions are not allowed.

How can I disable the exception support when using `boost::property_tree`?

If there's no way to do this, any recommendations for another library are very appreciated.

After the answer from @sehe, I tried this piece of code, but without success:

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

namespace boost {
    void throw_exception(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Fake exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        std::exit(255);
    }
}

class Foo {
    public:
      bool bar(const std::string file_name) {
        boost::property_tree::ptree prop_tree;
        boost::property_tree::read_ini(file_name, prop_tree);

        return !prop_tree.empty();
      }
};
```

The compilation line code uses the following parameters:

```
-c -DBOOST_USER_CONFIG="<user.hpp>" -DBOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DBOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE -I.\toolchain\boost -I.\include Foo.cpp
```

And finally, the `user.hpp` file:

```
#define BOOST_HAS_NRVO
#define BOOST_NO_COMPLETE_VALUE_INITIALIZATION
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_AUTO_DECLARATIONS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_AUTO_MULTIDECLARATIONS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR16_T
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR32_T
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE_N3276
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_EXPLICIT_CONVERSION_OPERATORS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_FINAL
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_FUNCTION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT_ARGS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_LAMBDAS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_LOCAL_CLASS_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NULLPTR
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RANGE_BASED_FOR
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RAW_LITERALS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_REF_QUALIFIERS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_STATIC_ASSERT
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIASES
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_UNICODE_LITERALS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_UNIFIED_INITIALIZATION_SYNTAX
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_USER_DEFINED_LITERALS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_VARIADIC_MACROS
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES
#define BOOST_NO_SFINAE_EXPR
#define BOOST_NO_TWO_PHASE_NAME_LOOKUP
```

Some errors returned by compiler:

```
"boost/optional/optional.hpp", line 1047: Error:  #312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::bad_optional_access" to "const std::exception" exists
            throw_exception(bad_optional_access());
                            ^

"boost/property_tree/string_path.hpp", line 221: Error:  #312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path" to "const std::exception" exists
          BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(ptree_bad_path("Path syntax error", *this));
          ^

"boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp", line 78: Error:  #742: namespace "boost" has no actual member "iterator_core_access"
          friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
                              ^
```

PS: I'm not using a widely-available standard compiler, but it's successfully compiling the `boost::smart_ptr`, using the same process described above.

Comment: Short answer - forget it. Boost isn't the answer here. Parsing ini files is trivial, and `property_tree` hugely complicates this with an inadequate error-handling strategy. The overhead is just not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Boost Exception to not use exceptions:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/exception/doc/configuration_macros.html

You need to define `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` and further implement your own C-style exception handling function, like e.g.

```
void throw_exception(std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "Fake exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    std::exit(255);
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/135e18ae5ab593d2)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

namespace boost {
    void throw_exception(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "Fake exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        std::exit(255);
    }
}

using namespace boost::property_tree;

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    read_ini(std::cin, pt);

    write_ini(std::cout, pt.get_child("section5"));
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -fno-exceptions
```

This prints

```
./test <<< "[section1]"
Fake exception: No such node (section5)
```

Comment: I did this, but now I receive the following error: 
"boost/property_tree/string_path.hpp", line 221: Error:  #312: no suitable user-defined conversion from "boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path" to "const std::exception" exists
          BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_THROW(ptree_bad_path("Path syntax error", *this));

Comment: @Valmir It seems you haven't shown enough code. It might well be you stumbled on a bug there but it's impossible to tell without the minimal selfcontained code sample